# make new button programatically from sync task

Tags: android, button

I'm my main activity I'm calling a sync task (consider its name is jjj)
so I call it in my main activity using

`new jjj().execute(variable name)`

I want inside the class named "jjj" to create a button dynamically/programatically which to be placed on the main activity xml

and when using

```
Button btn1 = new Button(this);
```

the program can crach

I think the problem in the word "this"
how can I do the needed functionality ?

Comment: from a non static async task:`new Button(getContext()):` From a static asyncTask you need to pass your context in through the constructor `new jjj(this);`

Comment: if using `getContext()` it gives error : The method getContext() is undefined for the type MainActivity.jjj  and if I used getBaseContext() instead, the program crashes while running

Answer (score 0):

> I think the problem in the word "this"

yes, to simplify things : a `View` need an `Activity` as its `constructor` (referred as `this`, in the `Activity`).

`AsyncTask` does not extends `Activity`, hence :

1. You can use `getContext()` method -> `Button btn1 = new Button(getContext());`
2. You can pass the `context` of `Activity` to the constructor of your `AsyncTask`

Comment: `You can pass the context of Activity to the constructor of your AsyncTask' I'm new in android can you write me example of code please to pass the context and use it with the getContext()

Comment: @FastSolutions that's a java syntax, not Android. Google `constructor`